# how can i sort column headers along with values A to Z (Alphabetically) with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, filter, header

I am trying to run the macro from sheet1 to sort the column by headers A to Z using VBA in sheet2. Anyone can help me to find it out.

[image: Demo Image]

```
Sub Macro1()
Range("C10:K13").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C10:K10") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
    .SetRange Range("C10:K13")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't sort horizontally so I transformed your range into vertical to sort and return the original value after sorting through the `transpose function`, this is my approach:

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range, transposeRng As Range
Set rng = sheets("Sheet2").[C10:K10]: Set transposeRng = sheets("Sheet2").[M6].Resize(rng.Columns.Count, rng.Rows.Count)
transposeRng.Value = Application.Transpose(rng)

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=transposeRng.Columns(1) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
        .SetRange transposeRng
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    transposeRng.Clear
    rng.Value = Application.Transpose(transposeRng)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sir here a problem accur in code, please rectify....ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=transposeRng.Columns(1) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal